# Query nodes and attributes of parent ways

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Does the Overpass API provide a way to query a list of nodes and some attributes of their parent ways, and return the data in CSV format?

For example, the following will give me all motorway junctions:

```
[out:csv(ref, name, ::lat, ::lon)];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “highway=milestone”
  node["highway"="motorway_junction"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Is there a way to query the `ref=*` tag of the roads of which the node is a member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```
[out:csv(_ref, name, ::lat, ::lon)];
node["highway"="motorway_junction"]({{bbox}});

foreach {                  // iterate over nodes

  way(bn)[highway~"^(motorway|trunk)$"][ref] -> .ways; // find ways for each node
  if (ways.count(ways) > 0) {                    // check that at least 1 way was found
    convert result                               // assemble result
             ::id   = id(),                      // use node id
             ::geom = center(geom()),            // and node position
             _ref    = ways.u(t["ref"]),         // parent ref tag
             ::     = ::;                        // all remaining tags of the node
    out geom;                                    // print node
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ve edited the answer to include also trunk roads. There are still issues to be solved where multiple ways with different `ref` tags are involved: either different spellings (`A8` vs. `A 8`), or the road name actually changes at the junction (`A2` becoming `S8`). The solution to that probably depends on the use case: I would want two rows, one for each road, so it’s probably better to search for the roads and iterate over its junctions.

Comment: To have one single entry for each of the ".ways", you'd need to add another foreach loop and iterate over those ways.

Comment: So I’ve replaced the `if` with another `foreach`, and I get short of 200 results (which looks OK). Problem is, how can I refer to tags of the way from the inner `foreach`?

Comment: Try this one: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/JY8

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks again!